# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError in Connection Factory

Tags: java, jdbc

Hi Below is my code which will use as Connection Factory class. But i am getting java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError. Please advice how to fix? I assume this is the trap because of static block, but not aware what exactly is this.

```
package j2ee.dao;  
import java.sql.Connection;  
import java.sql.DriverManager;  
import java.util.Properties;  

public class ConnFactory  
{  
    public static  Properties prop;  
    static   
    {  
        prop=new Properties();  
        try {  
            prop.load(ConnFactory.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("DBConfig.properties"));  

        } catch (Exception e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }     
    }  

    private static ConnFactory instance = new ConnFactory();  
    public static final String URL = prop.getProperty("DEVURL");  
    public static final String USER = prop.getProperty("DEVUSER");  
    public static final String PASSWORD = prop.getProperty("DEVPASSWORD");  
    public static final String DRIVER_CLASS = prop.getProperty("DEVDRIVER_CLASS");  

    private ConnFactory() {  
        try {  
            Class.forName(DRIVER_CLASS);  
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
    }  

    private Connection createConnection() {  
        Connection connection = null;  
        try {  
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);  
        } catch (Exception e) {  
            System.out.println("ERROR: Unable to Connect to Database.");  
        }  
        return connection;  
    }    

    public static Connection getConnection() {  
        return instance.createConnection();  
    }  
    public static void main(String a[])  
    {  
        Connection test=ConnFactory.getConnection();  
        System.out.println("Done");  

    }  

}
```

Error is :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:188)
    at j2ee.dao.ConnFactory.<init>(ConnFactory.java:28)
    at j2ee.dao.ConnFactory.<clinit>(ConnFactory.java:20)
```

Comment: Can you put in the whole exception stack trace?

Comment: Stack Trace is there now.

Comment: The error is self explainable. DRIVER_CLASS string is null. prop.getProperty("DEV_DRIVER_CLASS") is not returning anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static ConnFactory instance = new ConnFactory(); // DRIVER_CLASS is null at this point
...
public static final String DRIVER_CLASS = ...;
```

You create an instance of `ConnFactory` before `DRIVER_CLASS` is initialized, therefore `DRIVER_CLASS` is `null` in the constructor of `ConnFactory`.

You need to reverse the order of these static field declarations:

```
public static final String DRIVER_CLASS = ...;
...
private static ConnFactory instance = new ConnFactory()
```

Actually, in my opinion it would be better to get rid of these static fields at all. Just make them non-static and initialize them in constructor.

You can also pass an instance of `Properties` into constuctor to decouple connection creation from storage of connection properties. If you do so, you will be able to use different sets of properties in different cases (for example, for test and production environments).